# Working on making a random food generator

Tags: python, rest

I'd like to know how to use the result of the random choice into a follow up input prompt to avoid having to create if's for every food option. I later want that result to google search the nearest place that has the item available.

```
import random
import requests

def food(list):
    list= ["Crab Rangoon", "Sushi", "Ramen", "Bubble Tea", "Hot Pot", "Ice Cream", "Tostec",
           "Ovinhos", "Mango", "Pineapple", "Pad Thai", "Udon", "Lamb Corma",
           "Rice Beans and Steak with Plaintains and Tostones", "Tacos"]
    list = random.choice(list)
    print(list)
    if list == list:
        input("Would you like to search for " + list
        ' in your area? '
```

Comment: Please don't try to `overshadow` Python built-in `list` as the variable name here.   And What's your intent - expected output?

Comment: What is `list == list` supposed to do? That will always evaluate to `True` as memory location checking is used by python if there is no explicit equals method.

Comment: My intent is to randomly pick a food item, ask the user if they would like the item, and if yes then search for the nearest place for it.

Comment: list == list was my attempt at using the result of the random option into my input prompt.

Comment: @kingslyr then that if block would be unnecessary. You can just ask for the input immediately.

Comment: @EricJin Oh wow, thank you! That should solve my issue.

Comment: you shouldn't use name `list` because there is function `list()`. You use the same name `list` in `def food(list)` and `list = [...]` so you replace values which you send in `food([some,values])` with your inner `["Crab Rangoon", ...]`. You don't need `if list == list` because it compare exactly the same values and it will be always `True`. You should keep result from `input()` to use it later - `answer = input(...)`

Comment: maybe you should create more readable variables and i.e `def food(arg_foods)` `all_foods  = ["Crab Rangoon", ...]` (and this list you can even define outside function). `selected_food = random....`